# Measure LiPo Battery Cells with Voltage Divider?

Tags: voltage, voltage-divider, lipo

First, I am new in this topic, so please excuse unnecessary questions.

I want to measure the (four) cells of my lipo battery. The connector of the battery has a plus pole and four minus poles. (Image)

[image: battery cell connector]

Now I want to measure the cells with the Raspberry Pi, which max. voltage is 3.3 Volt. I use the ADS1115 to add analog pins to the RPi (works well).

So I drawn a schematic for a voltage divider to bring the max. 16.8V to 3.3V (works well)

[image]

Now my problem:

How I make the schematic bigger, because if I connect every battery minus to ground I am not able to measure the difference.

I want a different measurement for every cell.

EDIT:

**Solution [by Elliot Alderson]:**

[image: Solution]

Comment: No you can’t. Draw all cells and the ground connection and you will see where the fire starts.

Comment: Ok, what are the possible ways to measure the cells separately?

Comment: I'd be interested to see the internal wiring for the cells in the battery. I don't see how having one positive and 4 negatives works to use the cells individually. Are you sure it isn't +/- and something else like a thermistor?

Comment: @Alwin07 Connect the red (+) lead of your voltmeter to the red lead of the connector shown. Connect the black (-) lead of your voltmeter to each of the individual black leads, one at a time, and report the figures you get from the voltmeter (and which of the black leads it applies to.) Some batteries are used in series, but provide individual connections for parallel charging. Some have thermistors. Etc. You've provided too little information for any certainty. Perhaps you could also provide the model/manufacturer of the battery?

Comment: The battery: https://www.amazon.com/TATTU-2300mAh-Battery-Racing-Drones/dp/B013I9SVD2

Comment: Alwin, one of the reasons you are buying from Amazon is that they are low cost. One of the reasons they are low cost is that they typically don't provide datasheets for their products. We shouldn't really be doing tech support for Amazon. Our motto is, "No datasheet? No sale!"

Comment: This is an 'industry standard' connector used on almost all modern 'RC hobby' Lipo batteries. No datasheet required! Only the outside black wire is negative, all the others go to inter-cell connections. And of course there are no protection devices in the battery...

Comment: @RonBeyer Now that we know that it's an RC battery we can confidently assume that the connector is not one + and 4 - but rather one +, 3 +/- depending on how you measure, and one -. Each wire is soldered directly to the junction between one cell and the next except for the first which is wired to the first cell's + and last which is wired to the last cell's -

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to connect the "bottom" of your voltage divider to ground, but **do not** make any additional connections between ground and your batteries.

So, you will need to use four voltage dividers. The first will measure the voltage from cell 1, the second will measure the total voltage of cell 1 + cell 2, and so on.

In your software, measure the voltage for cell 1. You will need to convert the ADC reading to the actual corresponding voltage. Now measure the voltage for cell 1 + cell 2. Convert the ADC reading to actual volts and **subtract** the previously calculated voltage for cell 1 alone. Now you have the voltage for cell 2. Repeat for all four dividers.

Comment: I tried to draw a schematic with your answer. Schematic: https://i.imgur.com/7VawiKQ.png Sadly it is **not working**.

Comment: Only the cell which is connected to GND shows the right voltage. E.g. If I connect GND to "All Cells" Only the fourth cell shows the right value.

Comment: The connections to the ADC inputs are fine, don't change those. Now **disconnect** the 7.5k resistors from Cell1, Cell1+2, and Cell1+2+3 and connect them all to ground (the common Cell -). Disconnect R6, R7, and R8 from AllCells. Connect R6 to Cell1, R7 to Cell1+2, and R8 to Cell1+2+3. You may need to change the resistor values so that each divider gives about3V when the cells are fully charged.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have posted the new schematic in the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is not directly connected to your question but it will surely help. I suggest you to put an opamp as buffer after voltage divider output. And RC network to filter some noises caused by voltage divider resistances and opamp.